# Why do I need the subtraction for this generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm reading George E. Martin's: *The art of enumerative combinatorics*. In here:

> [image]

I don't understand why the need of the subtraction here. Could you expand a little more?

Comment: To kill all but finitely many terms and get a formula. The particular subtraction makes the terms that are vertically aligned cancel.

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is that apparently coefficients $F2-F1-F0=0$, as well as $F3-F2-F1=0$, and $F4-F3-F2=0$ with respect to their z-power, etc causing all terms to collapse. That is the need for the subtraction. Now as to WHY this cancellation happens, that I do not know. Hopefully somebody else may comment on that...

Comment: @imranfat They cancel because that is the definition of the Fibonacci sequence. $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ (or $F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}-F_n=0$).